# Does there exist an orthogonality concept for a multiple-way-dot product and if so, what would it mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

So I just revisited [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137102/dot-product-for-3-vectors) and I got curious if it would be possible to define some sort of "co-orthogonality" or "multiple-way-orthogonality" of dot products of multiple vectors and how it could be interpreted. Is there something special algebraically or geometrically which happens when the "dot product" between vectors $\bf a,b,c$ is zero?

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i c_i = 0$$

---

**Own work:**

We could take the special case if $\bf b$ is all ones except for one zero. Then in three dimensions $\bf a,b,c$ would be co-orthogonal in a plane spanned by $\bf 1-b$ *and* whenever $\bf a$ and $\bf c$ would be orthogonal to each other when projected onto the ${\bf b}=1$ dimensions.

Comment: If you know the vector product, you have $a\cdot (b\times c)$ which is zero when $a,b,c$ are coplanar.

Comment: The sum $\sum a_ib_ic_i$ doesn't behave like a scalar under inversions (reflections).