# Inequality for A Product of Orthonormal Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Suppose that $a,b,c$ are orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ($n\ge 3$).  How large can $|\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}c_{k}|$ be as a function of $n$?

I'm also generally interested in any inequalities or just theory/background information about sums of this form.

Comment: Define a new vector $d$ with $d_k=b_kc_k$; then we have the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$|a\cdot d|\leq\lVert a\rVert\lVert d\rVert=\lVert d\rVert=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n|b_kc_k|^2}$$ and since $|c_k|\leq1$, this is $$\leq\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n|b_k|^2}=\lVert b\rVert=1.$$ But there may be smaller bounds...

Comment: @mr_e_man Similar ideas give $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k b_k c_k\le ||a||\cdot||b||\cdot||c||$.  However, anything along the lines of Cauchy Schwarz or Holder seems to not use the orthogonality.

Comment: A similar question appears here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595189/does-there-exist-an-orthogonality-concept-for-a-multiple-way-dot-product-and-if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Holder inequality gives that

$$|\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}c_{k}|\le \|{a}\|_{3}\|{b}\|_{3}\|{c}\|_{3}$$

for any vectors $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ or $\mathbb{C}^{n}$.  The question was whether orthogonality of $a,b,c$ might allow for a smaller lower bound.  It does not.

For an example in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, take $a = (1,-1,-1,1), b=(-1,1,-1,1), c=(-1,-1,1,1)$.  Then $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}c_{k} = 4 = \|a\|_{3}\|b\|_{3}\|c\|_{3}$

In $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, certain Fourier basis vectors give an example where the worst case is achieved.  Let $3|n$, and let $k_{1} = n/3$, $k_{2} = 2n/3$. Let $\omega$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity.  Then take $a = (\omega^{k_{1}},\omega^{2k_{1}},\ldots, \omega^{nk_{1}}), b =(\omega^{k_{2}},\omega^{2k_{2}},\ldots, \omega^{nk_{2}}), c = (1,\ldots, 1)$.  Then

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}c_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}1 = n = \|a\|_{3}\|b\|_{3}\|c\|_{3}
$$
There are simpler examples in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, but this generalizes easily.