# "Orthogonality" for more than two vectors. How to interpret it?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, soft-question, tensor-products, orthogonality

Background to this question is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137102/dot-product-for-3-vectors/1137128#1137128) about how to express a dot product between a set of more than $2$ vectors:

$$({\bf v_1} \cdot {\bf v_2} \cdots {\bf v_n})=\sum_{\forall j}\prod_{i=1}^n({\bf v_i})_j$$

Now to my question : how would orthogonality, in other words: $$({\bf v_1} \cdot {\bf v_2} \cdots {\bf v_n}) = 0$$ be interpreted for such a construction? Would it be meaningful?

---

**Own work**

We can take $2D$ for example. Vectors $(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)$ are orthogonal to each other with this definition. So will any set containing $0$ in positions.

$(1,-1),(1,1),(0,1)$ will not be orthogonal to one another, despite $(1,-1),(1,1)$ being. So zero scalars can also be used to remove orthogonality.

For example this can work as a filter, consider the bigger $5D$ space:

$(1,-1,2,3,4),(1,1,4,3,2)$ are not orthogonal to one another, but components in two first dimensions are. So we add a third "filter" or "indicator" vector $(1,1,0,0,0)$ letting position 1 and 2 "survive" but removing the rest from the space. Like a special case of projection.

$(1,-1,2,3,4),(1,1,4,3,2),(1,1,0,0,0)$ will be orthogonal to one another because $(1,-1),(1,1)$ in the "shrunk" subspace are.

But this is merely a practical consideration of what traditional dot product operations can be expressed with this dot product. Not what it actually "means" in it's own right (if it means anything, geometrically speaking).

Comment: Multilinear mapping from $V^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$? Judging from the fact that you tagged the label "tensor-products" in this question, I guess you can find the desired solution by yourself. At least by the language of "tensor"

Comment: Generalize it to general measured spaces. What can you do with $\int f_1\ldots f_n d\mu = 0$ ?

Comment: It is as you say a multilinear mapping function and I suppose therefore it fits the tensor framework, but this fact alone does not help me gain a geometric intuition for what it does or means.

Comment: I like Gribouillis' idea. I think that you aren't going to get any geometric intuition for this operation. Like what is the collection of linear transformations that preserve this operation? E.g. for true inner products the unitary matrices preserve the inner product, but do any (non-trivial) linear transformations preserve this triple product?

Comment: @Gribouillis the definition can surely be useful at least for many engineering applications, but this question I can't really work out geometrically how to interpret it.

Comment: @KeeferRowan I am also sceptical if I will be able to find any intuition for it. The fact that we can use filtering in the way described should make it disqualified for being invariant for almost any transformation.

Comment: I suspect only permutations of the components preserve the operation (or composition with measure preserving transformations in the case of measure spaces). You could perhaps relate this to ergodic theory.